# A ps command with the relevant options that shows the state / status of only ONE process

Tags: linux, terminal, process, ps

I start 2 processes in the background: `xeyes` and `xclock -update 1`. When I run this commane: `ps T o pid,tty,time,args,state` (this for to output state) it lists:

```
PID TT           TIME COMMAND                     S
   5875 pts/0    00:00:00 bash                        S
   5881 pts/0    00:00:01 xeyes                       S
   5921 pts/0    00:00:00 xclock -update 1            S
   6141 pts/0    00:00:00 sleep 100                   T
   6340 pts/0    00:00:00 ps T o pid,tty,time,args,st R
```

How can I print out the state for only one process? For instance if I want to print the state of only the `xeyes` process.

Answer (score 2):

The `ps` command offers several options to enable you to select what is included in the output. I suggest you take a look at `man ps` to see the options that it exposes.

If you want to list processes by the command name, you can use the `-C` option.  For example:

```
$ ps -C xeyes ... other options ...
```

You can also select a process by its process ID (if you know it already) using the `-p` option.  For example:

```
$ ps -p 5881 ... other options ...
```